# Under what license can I use /usr/share/dict/words?

Tags: license, dictionary

There are a few dictionaries on my system,

```
/usr/share/dict/words
/usr/share/dict/american-english
/usr/share/dict/british-english
/usr/share/dict/ngerman
...
```

and so on.

How are these files licensed to me? Which project / package provides them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to determine what package the files belong to. You can use `dpkg -S searchterm` for that. For example, `dpkg -S /usr/share/dict/american-english` yields:

```
wamerican: /usr/share/dict/american-english
```

So, the subject package is `wamerican`. All packages I know of have a copyright file in `/usr/share/doc/PACKAGE-NAME/copyright`. `wamerican` is not an exception, it's copyright file is in `/usr/share/doc/wamerican/copyright`.

Answer (score 1):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/wordlist

Find the license by clicking the specific package and looking at the copyright over on the right.

(Found this by googling /usr/share/dict/words, and the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix) said it was the wordlist package)

For example, the american-huge wordlist copyright is here: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/scowl/scowl_6-3/wamerican-huge.copyright